# unconfirmed bitcoin transaction since last 10 days

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

(0d868f6d6459be4b343ac6442c8d4c484fd28370c4e7753f59f8b8669ef828c3)
This is he transaction which i have  done at 16 december and it is still pending 
what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you paid a very low fee 53.223 sat/B

And the transaction may never get any confirmations a very little chance

In this case the transaction will be cancelled after a period of time and return to original address.

The next time you create a transaction you need to [look for current average fee](https://bitcoinfees.21.co/) which is now as an example 620 sat/B (Satoshi per byte).

Comment: "And the transaction may never get any confirmations"... Well, the fee-situation is bad at the moment. But you could send the same amount for a fee of 10,000 sat/b 3 months ago. If the lightningh network is published, the fees will probably go to zero again.